# Getting an "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am using Webpack & Babel to transpile some `ES6` code & I keep getting an `uncaught type error`. It also says: `loadZipData   @   bundle.js:98`

```
Uncaught TypeError: _LoadDataClass2.default is not a function
```

Here is the transpiled code:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /*  
     *  CREATED: 11.25.2015
     */

    "use strict";

    var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

    var _LoadDataClass = __webpack_require__(1);

    var _LoadDataClass2 = _interopRequireDefault(_LoadDataClass);

    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var main = (function () {
        function main() {
            _classCallCheck(this, main);
        }

        _createClass(main, [{
            key: "fade",
            value: function fade(direction, fadeWhat) {
                //http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/
                var div = document.getElementById(fadeWhat);
                if (direction === "in") {
                    div.style.opacity = 0;
                    (function fade() {
                        var val = parseFloat(div.style.opacity);
                        if (!((val += .01) > 1)) {
                            div.style.opacity = val;
                            requestAnimationFrame(fade);
                        }
                    })();
                } else {
                    (function fade() {
                        div.style.opacity = 1;
                        if ((div.style.opacity -= .01) < 0) {
                            div.style.display = "none";
                        } else {
                            requestAnimationFrame(fade);
                        }
                    })();
                }
            }
        }, {
            key: "loadZipData",
                value: function loadZipData() {
  98                var zipData = new _LoadDataClass2.default();
                zipData.loadData("data/ZipCodeDatabase.csv", function (finalData) {
                    var zip = document.getElementById("studentZip").value;
                    for (var i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
                        if (zip == finalData[i][0]) {
                            document.getElementById("studentCity").innerText = finalData[i][1];
                            document.getElementById("studentState").innerText = finalData[i][2];
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }]);

        return main;
    })();

    window.onload = function () {
        var mainObject = new main();
        mainObject.fade("in", "ppsLogo");
        document.getElementById("studentZip").addEventListener("change", mainObject.loadZipData);
    };

/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    /*  
     *  CREATED: 11.25.2015
     */

    "use strict";

    var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var LoadDataClass = (function () {
        function LoadDataClass() {
            _classCallCheck(this, LoadDataClass);
        }

        _createClass(LoadDataClass, [{
            key: "loadData",
            value: function loadData(filePath, callback) {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", filePath, true);
                request.send();
                request.onload = function () {
                    var COLUMNS = 3;
                    var data = undefined,
                        middleData = undefined,
                        finalData = [];
                    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                        data = request.responseText.split(/\n/);
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        middleData = data[i].split(/,/);
                        finalData[i] = []; //makes it an MD array
                        for (var j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
                            finalData[i][j] = middleData[j];
                        }
                    }
                    callback(finalData);
                };
            }
        }]);

        return LoadDataClass;
    })();

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

The error happens on line 98. The rest of the code works fine.

Here is the original main class file:

```
"use strict";

import LoadDataClass from './LoadDataClass';

class main {
    constructor() {

    }

    fade(direction, fadeWhat) {
        //http://www.chrisbuttery.com/articles/fade-in-fade-out-with-javascript/
        let div = document.getElementById(fadeWhat);
        if (direction === "in") {
            div.style.opacity = 0;
            (function fade() {
                let val = parseFloat(div.style.opacity);
                if (!((val += .01) > 1)) {
                    div.style.opacity = val;
                    requestAnimationFrame(fade);
                }
            })();
        } else {
            (function fade() {
                div.style.opacity = 1;
                if ((div.style.opacity -= .01) < 0) {
                    div.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    requestAnimationFrame(fade);
                }
            })();
        }
    }

    loadZipData() {
        let zipData = new LoadDataClass();
        zipData.loadData("data/ZipCodeDatabase.csv",  function(finalData) {
            let zip = document.getElementById("studentZip").value;
            for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
                if (zip == finalData[i][0]) {
                    document.getElementById("studentCity").innerText = finalData[i][1];
                    document.getElementById("studentState").innerText = finalData[i][2];
                    console.log(finalData[i][1]);
                    console.log(finalData[i][2]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    let mainObject = new main();
    mainObject.fade("in","ppsLogo");
    document.getElementById("studentZip").addEventListener("change", mainObject.loadZipData);
};
```

Comment: i have to count the lines? And also it would be better to include `devTool` into your webpack config to make you debugging more easy [Link](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) for you

Comment: I identified line 98. Sorry about that.

Comment: Could you add a _js file_ which contains this function? Its quite difficult to find where the problem is in your bundle.js file. this is your main _js_ file

Comment: Does `./LoadDataClass` have a default export? If not, then this won't work. The compiled source makes it look like that there is no export at all. Do you know how ES6 modules work? If not I suggest to read something about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export .

Comment: @FelixKling: That was it. I TOTALLY forgot to export. If you answer, I will mark as correct answer. Thanks!